# Changing the number of scrolled products in the carousel after clicking the prev/next arrow

Tags: orocommerce, orocrm

I tried to change default behavior od prev/next button in featured products carousel. For example:  I want to have scrolled next 4 items after clicking once next arrow. There is any posibility to configure that in yaml or should I change something in JS? And if it is matter of JS where can I find the logic responsible for?

I tried to find a solution with yaml configuration so far.

Answer (score 1):

The featured products carousel uses a slick slider under the hood, so you can use any options that present in their [documentation](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) by `yml` file. For instance change a behavior of slider on home page

```
# layouts/default/oro_frontend_root/featured_products.yml
- '@setOption':
    id: featured_products
    optionName: slider_options
    optionValue:
        slidesToShow: 4
        slidesToScroll: 4
        arrows: true
        responsive:
            - { breakpoint: 1100, settings: { arrows: true } }
            - { breakpoint: 993, settings: { slidesToShow: 3, arrows: true } }
            - { breakpoint: 768, settings: { slidesToShow: 2, arrows: true } }
            - { breakpoint: 641, settings: { slidesToShow: 1, arrows: true } }
```

There is JS that responsible for it: [list-slider-component](https://github.com/oroinc/customer-portal/blob/master/src/Oro/Bundle/FrontendBundle/Resources/public/js/app/components/list-slider-component.js)